# google cloud print , "Save to Google Drive" not working

Tags: gnome, printing, pdf, cloud, google

I no longer have the option to `Save to Google Drive` in my printer dialog.
I am logged into my google account with Online Accounts.
On my account page at [google.com](https://google.com), I see that Gnome has access to Google Cloud Print.

Could this have to do with two factor authentication which recently I am 'forced' to use?

Comment: You have an answer to this but you should be aware this is off topic here. It has nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS or any supplied program.

Answer (score 1):

turns out it's no longer available
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006?hl=en

> Save to Google Drive from print preview
>
> After December 2020, the “Save to Drive” option won't be available for
> Windows, MacOS, and Linux devices. You can save documents to Google
> Drive from print preview.